# "seines Zeichens" und "leicht zu durchschauendes"

Tags: idiom, vocabulary

DE: Ich bin Bulgare und weiß worum es geht, verstehe aber nicht was "seines Zeichens" hier zu bedeuten hat.

> Für diesen Machterhalt benötigt Borissow Verbündete. Seine jetzigen Koalitionspartner sind die "Vereinten Patrioten", ein Bündnis ultranationalistischer und rechtsextremer Parteien unter Führung des Verteidigungsministers und Vize-Premiers Krassimir Karakatschanow, seines Zeichens ehemaliger Informant des kommunistischen Geheimdienstes. Die Vereinten Patrioten haben eine stabile Wählerschaft von etwa zehn Prozent. Sie spielen eine erhebliche Rolle für den Machterhalt von GERB.

ENG: Also, what does "ein leicht zu durchschauendes" mean? Google Translate says "easily understandable", but it isn't in the infinitive, i.e. *leicht zu durchschauen*.

> Die Forderungen Bulgariens an Nordmazedonien sind anmaßend und unwissenschaftlich - ein leicht zu durchschauendes innenpolitisch motiviertes Unterfangen. Das Mobbing Nordmazedoniens durch Bulgarien muss beendet werden.

Source: https://www.dw.com/de/wer-stoppt-bulgariens-mobbing-gegen-nordmazedonien/a-55678990

Comment: Auch wenn es auf eine Quelle zurückgeht, sind es doch 2 Fragen - die richtige Antwort für die eine beeinflusst nicht die für die andere. Daher soll die Frage gesplittet werden. Man weiß sonst auch nicht, ob man eine Antwort, die nur eine der Fragen beantwortet, belohnen soll, wann die Frage insges. als beantwortet zu gelten hat (Häkchen).

Answer (score 4):

> seines Zeichens ehemaliger Informant des kommunistischen Geheimdienstes

Das ist ein *genitivus absolutus*. *Seines Zeichens* leitet die Beschreibung einer Ausbildung oder ausgeübten Tätigkeit ein.

> ein leicht zu durchschauendes innenpolitisch motiviertes Unterfangen

Das ist ein großer Nominalausdruck. Dafür ist Deutsch ja berüchtigt. Der Teil *leicht zu durchschauendes* ist ein Partizipialausdruck – die funktionieren wie ein Adjektiv und werden daher auch dekliniert.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure now whether I should answer in English or German. I will do it in English.

- `"Seines Zeichens"` is derived from the previously used signs for a certain guild (professional group).
  So it indicates a certain professional group.
- "Durchschaubar" means "transparent" or "predictable" in the sense of comprehensible, understandable.
  Therefore something can be `leicht zu durchschauen` or `easy to understand` as you've already said.
  In this case it must be `durchschauendes` for the same reason that it is `innenpolitisch motiviertes` and not `innenpolitisch motiviert`.
  It is treated as an adjective.

Comment: "Seines Zeichens ehemaliger Informant des kommunistischen Geheimdienstes" is IMHO a bit ironic. It's worded as if secret service informant were a respected profession.

Answer (score 1):

**Frage 1:**

Die Redewendung "seines Zeichens" dient der *Betonung* der Zugehörigkeit zu einer bestimmten (Berufs-) Gruppe. Sachlich ist sie immer überflüssig. Im zitierten Text hätte es auch gereicht zu sagen

> unter Führung des Verteidigungsministers und Vize-Premiers Krassimir Karakatschanow, eines ehemaligen Informanten des kommunistischen Geheimdienstes.

[Zitat](https://www.nextz.de/glossen/seines-zeichens.htm):

*Einst bezog sich der Ausdruck nur auf Berufe und beschrieb die Zugehörigkeit zu einem Berufsstand, das hat sich heute allerdings gelockert. Vor langer Zeit gab es den Brauch, dass wandernde Gesellen - wenn sich mehrere von ihnen in einer Herberge trafen - ihr Gesellenzeichen auf den Tisch malten. Beim feierlichen Vorstellen mit Handwerksgruß und Umtrunk wurde nun jeder mit den Worten vorgestellt: Das ist Soundso, er ist seines Zeichens Schmied oder Zimmermann oder Maurer.*

Meiner Meinung nach hat RHa in seinem Kommentar Recht, wenn er im Kontext der Frage eine ironisch/sarkastische Bedeutung erkennt.

**Frage 2:**

Der Ausdruck "ein leicht zu durchschauendes innenpolitisch motiviertes Unterfangen" bedeutet

> es ist leicht zu durchschauen, dass es sich um  ein innenpolitisch motiviertes Unterfangen handelt.

Google Translate hat also nicht unrecht mit dem Vorschlag

> it is easily understandable that ...

Ich würde allerdings eher folgendes sagen:

> it is easily comprehensible that ...